# Injecting ResourceBundle in Spring Bean

Tags: spring

I want to inject a resource bundle into a bean. I need the resourcebundle, I can't get the messages directly. I am using this snippet to load the resource:

```
 <bean id="reportMessages" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>report.messages</value>
        </property>
```

Then I can inject it into my bean like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("reportMessages")
private ResourceBundleMessageSource reportMessages;
```

But this gives me a ResourceBundleMessageSource, which has a getResourceBundle() method which is protected and thus I can't call it.

I.e. what I want is Spring's built-in functionality to read a Message Bundle depending on locale, and then treat it as a separate bean.

Comment: Why. Why do you want the bundle instead of the `MessageSource` which abstracts that away.

Comment: Because I need to feed a jasper report with a `ResourceBundle`, and their api only accepts that

Comment: Wrap the `MessageSource` in a `MessageSourceResourceBundle`.

Comment: Can you expand on that with a bit of code please? I'm not sure how to obtain a MessageSource object

Comment: You are already retrieving a `MessageSource` the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` IS A `MessageSource`... just wrap that in a `MessageSourceResourceBundle` and pass that to JasperReport(s). That is also what Spring does in its own JasperReports support.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same situtation as OP did, and M. Deinum 's comment to wrap `MessageSource` with `MessageSourceResourceBundle` solved my issue.

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);
    /* wrap the annotated messageSource with MessageSourceResourceBundle */
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE, new MessageSourceResourceBundle(messageSource, locale));
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible this [part of documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-functionality-messagesource) will be helpful. In your beans you should to use `MessageSource`. In controller, or service or any other bean you can use it next way:

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    ....

    @RequestMapping("/messages")
    public String showMessages(ModelMap model) {

        String englishMessage = messageSource.getMessage("commend.message", null, 
            new Locale("en", "US"));
        String russianhMessage = messageSource.getMessage("commend.message", null, 
            new Locale("ru", "RU"));
        ...
    }
}
```

And in view (if you use JSP, of cause):

```
<div>
    <span>
        <spring:message code="commend.message"/>
    </span>
</div>

...
```

Now about configuration. I would advice you to keep default id of `ResourceBundleMessageSource` bean. Default id is `messageSource`:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
     <property name="basename">
          <value>report.messages</value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

Of cause, you can autowire this bean by `@Qualifier` annotation, as you did. But most of templaters (JSP, Thymeleaf and others) will be looking for `messageSource` bean, by default. So if you'll keep default name, you will not need to change settings of template engines.

Don't forget to put in root of classpath of your application property files with messages for every needed language. In this example it will `report.messages.properties` (default), `report.messages_en_US.properties` and `report.messages_ru_RU.properties`.